# Can i use android toolbar with bottom navigation bar?

Tags: android, android-studio, toolbar

I used bottom navigation bar on my app. And I also want to use a toolbar to use a search filter.
I know that I need a menu.xml to use a toolbar but I already made menu.xml to use the bottom navigation bar.
If i use a toolbar on my app, do i have to made a new menu.xml?

Though I included more instances in bottom navigation bar's menu.xml, I couldn't do anything

Answer (score 1):

Both don't need to be the same name (menu.xml) and can have different names (eg: bottom_nav_menu.xml for navigation & top_menu.xml for toolbar)